# Django / React Cross-Origin Request Blocked Error hosted Google App Engine django-cors-headers not working

Tags: python, django, reactjs, google-app-engine, django-cors-headers

The application backend (django) and frontend (react) are hosted on google cloud at the same app. 
I've installed django-cors-headers and referred to it in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'https?\://myapp\.appspot\.com\/?',
    'https?\://frontend-dot-myapp\.appspot\.com\/?',
)
```

As far as I understood CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL should already resolve this problem, but it doesn't, I just got a bit desparate there trying things out. CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST didn't work as well for me that's why CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST.

I haven't changed anything in this setup but now the Cross-Origin error appears. Since the last code change I installed django-silk to profile the app. Removing it doesn't appear to resolve the issue, so I'm not sure whether it's related.

Help greatly appreciated!

in requirements.txt:
`django-cors-headers==3.2.1`

EDIT

After a lot of trial and error I found adding the last two lines in urls.py cause the problem:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', views.api_root),
    path('_ah/warmup/', views.service_status),
    path('_ah/start/', views.service_status),
    ...
```

However I don't understand why that causes the CORS error or how to resolve it.

Comment: I am not sure but may be [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#cors-support) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I should've mentioned I run into this problem with the script handler, that appears to only work for static file handlers. I've tried it nonetheless but it was the same.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issue in project solution that i got is

1. Place corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware at the top

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE = [
   'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

   ]
   ```
2. ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
3. Add at the bottom of the settings.py

   ```
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This idea might be worth a shot. Try moving your `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` line to the top of the `MIDDLEWARE` section.

This is recommended in the [pypi django-cors-headers documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) where they say "CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django’s CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise’s WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these responses."

Comment: When you add those last two urls, do the `/api` and `/admin` still give a CORS error? And what is the status code? If it is in the 400 or 500 range, it might not be a CORS issue.

Comment: you are so right, it's not a CORS issue. I was getting that message because the 500 error triggered the CORS error. Thank you for the hint, don't know if I'd ever figure that out otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

Check here 'Content-Type':"application/json", if you type Contenttype or ContentType will give an error of CORS header blocked